# How to get microsoft c compiler to pre compute standard math functions for constants

Tags: c, visual-studio, optimization, math.h

GCC beautifully pre-computes the results of standard math functions at compile time when the input is a constant.

Anyone know how to do the same with Microsoft C? I've tried everything and so far no joy.

Code example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define FFT_SIZE_LOG2       10
#define CALC_FFT_SIZE(x)    (int)pow(2., (double)x)

int main (void)
{
    printf ("FFT size = %d\n", CALC_FFT_SIZE(FFT_SIZE_LOG2));
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: How did you verify that MSVC does not do this? (Use [edit] to add that in your question.)

Comment: It works fine with `1 << x` of course but I'm not sure what to do about your specific example

Comment: Do not use `pow` to compute integer powers of two. Poor implementations of `pow` return incorrect values, and, for many years, Microsoft’s implementation was one such. Powers of two are easily prepared using the bit-shift operator, `<<`.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.
@usr2564301 To verify I used :
cl -c -Fa -Ox log_size.c

Comment: @harold, << doesn't use the std math functions.

Comment: @Eric. I used pow() as a simple example. MSVC does not appear to be able to pre-compute any functions at compile time

Comment: Although `pow(2,10)` is an example, it is a weak one as `#define CALC_FFT_SIZE(x)    ((int)(1u << (x)))` is a reasonable alternative.  It would be better to post an example of a true need for compile time `<math.h>` pre-computation that does not have a trivial alternative..

Comment: How about this code :

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>
    int main (void)
    {
        printf ("log = %lf\n", log(7.1729383));
        return(0);
    }

Comment: I've had some great suggestions about how to optimize specific functions but none to suggest how to force Visual C/C++ to pre-compute any math.h function to a constant in the same way that GCC does.

I'm beginning to wonder if it is even possible or is this another area where GCC beats Microsoft ;-)